# Do html5 <video> tags perform at the same speed as <img> tags?

Tags: javascript, html

I’m trying to figure out if there are any negative outcomes from using `<video>` tags to display images (sometimes in a carousel) instead of `<img>` tags.

Would the best way to start be bench marking their performances?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why would you want to use `video` tags for images? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: It is a weird request, interesting question though.

Comment: The `<video>` tag on its own would not do anything. How well the display will perform, depends on the codec of the displayed video and on the system that does the decoding. So in theory a slideshow with blending which was preprocessed into a video could indeed perform better then a _js_  or _css_  driven slideshow. But that really depends on the browser, its version and the system it is running on.

Comment: I'm trying to render a bunch of input types (gif/jps/gifv/webm/mp4) without an explicit statement that is their type. So I'm wondering if the lazy way is just to always render in video tags (it works, just..is it fast?)

Comment: @t.niese In this case the video tag is rendering either a png/jpg/webm/mp4 (from what I can tell .gifvs from Imgur render in a ```<video>``` with ```<source>```s pointing to both the .mp4 and .webm.

Answer (score 0):

<video> tag is just HTML tag as <img>. Performance of rendering both tag should be same, all matter on which browser you are accessing this.  Also if you are using <video> tag, make sure you are using proper code to display video.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to respond. Can you clarify what you mean? I think my question might need reworded. I basically mean to ask if rendering an image in an <img> tag is as performant as rendering an image in a <video> (probably in the cover attribute).

Comment: Oh okay, I see what you're saying. Are there any references I can check out on this particular topic?